# How to Add new object in vuex and store image url through API call

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuex, directus

I am trying to learn vue but i am stuck at fetching data from API. i am using directusSDK for fetching data from directus and i am able to get data from API but i cannot store the image URL in new object in state, can someone tell me how to add new object property in state and store the image url on it.

Here's is my code

```
store/modules/models.js
import users  from "./../users"

const state =
{
    models: []
};

const getters =
{
   allModels: state =>state.models

};

const actions =
{
    async fetchModels({ commit }) {
        const response = await users.getItems("models");
        //console.log(response.data);
        commit('_SET_MODELS', response.data);
    },
    async getPic({commit, state}){
        state.models.forEach((element)=>{
            if (element != null) {
                users.getFiles("/Files"+ element.image)
                    .then(response => {
                        element["imgURL"] = response.data[1].data
                    }).then(result => commit('_GET_PIC', result.data)).catch(error => {
                        throw new Error(`API ${error}`);
                    })
            }
        })
    }
 };

const mutations =
{
    _SET_MODELS: (state, models) => (state.models = models),
    _GET_PIC: (state, models) => (state.models = models)
};


export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

**successfully fetching imgUrl**
I made changes to my code and its getting imgUrl from API but now the problem is its not getting right imgUrl instead its assigning random imgUrl.

**Here's my updated code:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import users from "./../users"

const state = {
    models: [],
    picture: []
};

const getters = {
    allModels: state => state.models

};

const actions = {
    async fetchModels({commit}) {
        await users.getItems("models").then(
            response => {
                commit('_SET_MODELS', response.data)
            }
        );
        var arrModels = state.models;
        arrModels.forEach((element, index) => {
            users.getFiles("/Files/" + element.image)
                .then(response => {
                    //console.log(response.data[index].data.full_url);
                    commit('_SET_PIC', {
                        index: index,
                        imgURL: response.data[index].data.full_url
                    });

                })
        })

    }


};


const mutations = {
    _SET_MODELS: (state, models) => (state.models = models),
    _SET_PIC: (state, args) => {
        let index = args.index;
        let imgURL = args.imgURL;
        Vue.set(state.models[index], 'imgURL', imgURL);
    }


};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According the Vuex documentation:

> Prefer initializing your store's initial state with all desired fields upfront.

But if you need to add some properties to the Vuex Object, you must use `set` method:

```
Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)
```

See the official documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules

Your code would be something like that:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import users from './../users';

const state = { models: [] };
const getters = { allModels: state => state.models };
const actions = {
  async fetchModels({ commit }) {
    const response = await users.getItems('models');
    commit('_SET_MODELS', response.data);
  },
  async getPic({ commit, state }) {
    state.models.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (element != null) {
        users
          .getFiles(`/Files${element.image}`)
          .then(response => {
            console.log('checking if the value is correct', response.data[1].data);
            commit('_SET_PIC', { index: index, imgURL: response.data[1].data });
          })
          // .then(result => commit('_GET_PIC', result.data)) // I don't understand this line
          .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(`API ${error}`);
          });
      }
    });
  },
};
const mutations = {
  _SET_MODELS: (state, models) => (state.models = models),
  // ADD THIS MUTATION
  _SET_PIC: (state, args) => {
    let index = args.index;
    let imgURL = args.imgURL;
    Vue.set(state.models[index], 'imgURL', imgURL);
  },
  _GET_PIC: (state, models) => (state.models = models),
};
export default { state, getters, actions, mutations };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but still the "imgURL" Not showing in my state. As i viewed in console

Comment: I found a problem in my code. I updated my answer. Please do a new test.

Comment: still nothing, hope you understand what i am trying to do, i am trying to fetch image url from api and want to store in models by creating new  object so i can access the img url to show in my vue app